# Symfony 2 toString 500 Internal

Tags: php, symfony

I keep getting the same error in symfony when I try to decode then return the array of post from ajax.

**Error:**

The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedValueException

**PHP**

```
public function ajaxAction(){

    $array = $_POST['json'];

    $arraydecode = json_decode($array);

    return new Response($arraydecode);

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encode your array first that you have a valid json string. Then return the string with the json content type.

```
$array = $_POST['json'];
$arraydecode = json_encode($array);

$response = new Response($arraycode);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

Comment: I was to return it as an array, if possible.

Comment: @BrentFrench you'd better return it as a JSON object and then in your JS code, use `JSON.parse()` to get your array.

Comment: You can't return an array. An array is not supported. The problem is how will you resolve the array? For that is the json format. That you have a defined format that you can use with other languages like javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You can use JsonResponse: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
//some code
return new JsonResponse($array);
```